# sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Tags: sudo, tty

I have a perl script that I fork from another script that I launch from a web browser via mod_perl.  The forked script (which ends up running as apache) needs to `sudo service X stop` as part of a backup restore process: the X service depends on the restore.  I had this running OK on Windows, but now porting to CentOS I'm running into the error in the title.

Setup:

1. sudoers file has commented out `# Defaults    requiretty`
2. sudoers file has `apache_usr localhost=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/service X stop` (which passes a `visudo -c` check) and has no other `apache_usr` lines

Things I've tried:

1. `sudo /sbin/service` instead of just `sudo service` in the forked process
2. sudoers file with or without commenting out `Defaults   !visiblepw`
3. sudoers file with `(ALL)` instead of `(root)` in the NOPASSWD line above

What else is there to try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short it's how sudo was designed. [See here](http://unix.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/FreeBSD/questions/2008-01/msg01081.html).

It does host lookups a bit differently so as not to lag when you don't have a network connection / fast DNS server.

If you machine name is 'salt' then your proper sudoers line is:

`apache_usr salt=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/service X stop`

In other words, localhost is not a valid host name as far as sudoers is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned that "sudoers file has commented out `# Defaults requiretty`".

This won't have any effect if your build of sudo has `requiretty` on by default, which mine does.  Use a targeted default spec for the user concerned:

```
Defaults:apache_usr !requiretty
```

Answer (score 0):

When I write `ALL=(root)` instead, it works.  Despite the fact that the script is running on the same server as the service I'm trying to stop.  It's accessed in the browser via a different IP than the main one, but nonetheless, if I run `ping -c 1 localhost` I get `127.0.0.1` so I'm really curious as to why this change needed to be made.